# Using the names of the objects being iterated upon in lapply

Tags: r, lapply

I would like to access the names of the elements of the objects in a list given as an input to lapply. The following is a contrived example of a desired behavior, in which I would just paste the name of the object and its content:

```
x <- list(a=1,b=2)
lapply(x, FUN) 
$a
[1] "a1"

$b
[1] "a2"
```

It is always possible to give to use `lapply()` on names of the list and then use `x[[name_element]]` in the function body, but I believe it makes the code less clear.

Comment: Because of the way it's constructed, `lapply()` doesn't ever have access to the name of the list element that it is currently operating on. Which means that, if you want to use `lapply()` this way, I think you just have to bite the bullet and use the names to index into the elements.

Answer (score 0):

`mapply` over the list and the names of the list:

```
x <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
y <- mapply(paste0, names(x), c(x), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

y
$a
[1] "a1"

$b
[1] "b2"
```

Comment: I am afraid you missed the part where I say "contrived example". The point is not to solve this simple toy problem, but the general problem, in which you do need lapply.

Comment: Gotcha. Then I believe `mapply` is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% what is your general problem, but here is another solution to the toy problem.

```
fun <- function(x) {
  lapply(x, function(elem) paste0(names(x)[[elem]], x[[elem]]))
}

fun(x)
$a
[1] "a1"

$b
[1] "b2"
```